# Error: "Expression must have class type" C++/CLI

Tags: .net, c++-cli, compiler-errors

Not sure why this won't compile. What sort of error am I making here and how do I fix it? I am trying to compile this code I found in an example but my compiler must have stricter settings than theirs or maybe a different version of compiler. The code should just open up a windows form and display some text.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Drawing;

public ref class MyForm : Form
{
public:

MyForm ()
    {
    Text = "Windows Forms Demo";
    }

void Main ()
    {
    Application.Run (gcnew MyForm());
    }

protected:
 void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    e.Graphics.DrawString ("Hello, world", Font,
        gcnew SolidBrush (Color.Black), ClientRectangle);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sorry error is on line "e.Graphics.DrawString" The e is highlighted and it says Expression must have a class type

Comment: Your compiler should give you some line information, and a detailed error message. Try to enable all warnings with your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You've written incorrect syntax to `override` and access methods.

```
 virtual void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs^ e) override
  {
    Form::OnPaint(e);
    e->Graphics->DrawString("Hello, world", gcnew System::Drawing::Font("Arial",20),  gcnew SolidBrush (Color::Black), ClientRectangle);
  }
```

and don't use `void main()`.

```
[STAThreadAttribute]
int main()
{
     Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is with `Font`, which is a class. The call expects a font, that is, a `Font` instance.